# Is there a way of seeing your longest pokeradar chain?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Like there was on diamond and pearl using the poketech?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the professor's office in Luminose City on the 2nd floor there are some PCs you can look at to see your highest chain.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily the pokemon radar, but you can check how long your biggest fishing chain went for by talking to the guy who gave you the Super Rod. He is in a building in Route 16.